# Does VB6 InputBox support a multi-line string?

Tags: vb6

When using InputBox in Visual Basic 6 can I input a multiline string?

```
strSrch = InputBox("Enter word(s) or phrase(s), like " & Chr(34) & "Jesus wept" & _ 
  Chr(34) & " to search for any word or phrase" & vbCrLf & _
  "If you place & between words the verse must contain both words, loved & world" & _
  vbCrLf & "or both phrases, " & Chr(34) & "keep the commandments" & Chr(34) & _
  " & " & Chr(34) & "of Jesus" & Chr(34) & vbCrLf & "Put ! in front of a word or phrase to exclude it from your search, Jesus ! testimony" & _
  vbCrLf & "Use( before and ) after expressions to group them together, (" & Chr(34) & _
  "Come unto me" & Chr(34) & " & all)" & vbCrLf & "Use Xor between two words to include one or the other but not both, " & _
  Chr(34) & "I am" & Chr(34) & " Xor that", "Word Search")
```

Comment: I don't think you can.  One option would be to create a form or usercontrol containing the functionality you need.

Comment: Thanks, Brian. I was hoping there was a way to allow the user to enter more than one line to do a complex search. Perhaps I could put an option to continue to another InputBox if he/she filled the first one with characters.

Comment: You could, but that would be a little clunky for the user.  And you have no way to modify the InputBox layout.  Creating a form with 2 multi-line text boxes and 2 buttons isn't that hard to do, and a much nicer experience for the user.  You also have complete control of everything on the form.

Comment: InputBox is a GUI port of Input command in MSDos Basics. So it is well depreciated. Edit controls, the part where you type, have a property of single line or multiline (as Notepad is). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-edit-controls

Comment: Looks like there is a way through this. Appreciate both of your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really.  IIRC, the InputBox *should* preserve any newline chars that are dropped into it via a paste or entered via ALT+###.  But, they will appear as spaces in the box. 
 It will only ever appear on a single line.  There's no real way to use an InputBox to let a user enter multiple lines.

The most feature-capable way to handle this would be to create a custom form and use it to collect user input.  You can make it a modal dialog to force the user to interact with it, similar to an InputBox.  There are a few ways to pass the input back to the procedure that displayed the form (such as using a global variable).